# Function simplification

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to express the following function more simply:

\begin{equation*} 
f(x) = (\sum_{n=3}^{x} \prod_{k=2}^{\lceil \sqrt n \rceil} \lceil \dfrac {n}{k} \rceil - \lfloor \dfrac{n}{k} \rfloor ) + 1 .
\end{equation*}

I know this is kind of a vague request, but I'm trying to get away from the ceiling and floor functions and possibly the product notation, just because it feels like a hacky way of expressing what I'm trying to express.

Any ideas?

Comment: This looks more like a computer program than a mathematical expression.

Comment: @muad: what is a computer program but a particular kind of mathematical expression?

Answer (score 12):

$\left\lceil \frac{n}{k} \right\rceil - \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor$ is equal to $0$ or $1$ depending on whether $k$ does or does not divide $n$.  In other words,

$$\prod_{k=2}^{ \lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil} \left( \left\lceil \frac{n}{k} \right\rceil - \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor \right)$$

is equal to $0$ or $1$ depending on whether $n$ is composite or prime.  So the function you are trying to describe is the [prime counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).  There really is no simpler way to describe it than "the prime counting function," although a lot is known about its asymptotic behavior.

Edit:  For functions like the prime counting function, you should replace the notion of "nice formula" with "fast algorithm" (the former being a special case of the latter).  The formula you wrote down is equivalent to a very slow algorithm: use trial division to test the primality of all the integers in your range.  There are much faster [primality tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) which translate into much faster algorithms for computing $\pi(n)$ even though these tests cannot be easily translated into familiar-looking formulas.

Edit #2:  As Shreevatsar mentions in the comments, [sieve theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_theory) is also relevant to  counting or estimating $\pi(n)$ more directly, without having to do all that primality testing.

Comment: By the way, the idea behind your formula is not a bad idea at all; it is clever to take advantage of the fact that a product of 0s and 1s is 1 if and only if all of the factors are 1, and such ideas are often useful for computing other things and in other areas of mathematics; see e.g. the standard proof of the [Chevalley-Warning theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Warning_theorem).

Comment: +1. For computation of the prime-counting function, where you're counting all primes in a large range, having faster sieves would be more useful than faster primality tests directly. There are a few references on the Wikipedia page, though I think it's incomplete… of course, if you don't want the *exact* value of π(n) there are much faster approaches that are asymptotically right.

Comment: +1. "[..] you should replace the notion of "nice formula" with "fast algorithm" (the former being a special case of the latter)." I like this observation. Wondering if all functions have algorithms that compute them eventually led me to the concept of computable function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function

Comment: "Nice formulas" aren't necessarily special cases of fast algorithms. Perhaps that's what you intended to say above.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque:  I guess you are right.  I was being a little imprecise.  I mean something vaguer than "special case" but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that you seek a concise formula (versus a fast algorithm), then one can simplify it somewhat by replacing the product by a factorial, and by employing $\rm\;\; a\perp b \;\; := \; 1 \;\;\; if \;\;\; gcd(a,b)=1 \;\;\; else \;\;\; 0$

$$\rm \pi(x) \: = \: \sum_{n\;=\;2}^x \;\: n\perp {\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor}!$$

Comment: If you are willing to introduce this perpendicular notation wouldn't it be even easier to just define the indicator function of the primes?

Comment: Said function is just the "coprime" predicate, which is obviously more general and more efficiently computable than is the "prime" predicate. Of course it will be a matter of taste what one permits as "nice" functions. In computational number theory, for efficiency, one often works with factorizations into coprimes rather than primes, e.g. google "gcd-free basis".

Comment: Sure, but that efficiency gain is more than offset by the fact that the number you need to compute a gcd with respect to is huge.

Comment: Not necessarily, since the products in the factorial need only be computed mod n. In any case, as I said, I presumed the OP was interested interested in "nice formulas", not efficiency, since his original formula is already very inefficient. My remark about the utility of the coprime predicate and gcd-free bases were meant merely as background motivation to explain why the coprime predicate does in fact arise naturally in computational contexts. The utility of gcd-free bases deserves to be much better known.

Answer (score 0):

It depends in what context you want to define that function (for computer implementations?), but following Qiaochu Yuan's post, you can e.g. use set-based notations to state the primality test more clearly.

$$f(x) = \left| \lbrace x \in \lbrace 3,\ldots, x \rbrace \; |\; \forall k \in \lbrace 2,\ldots,\sqrt n \rbrace . k \not | \; n \rbrace \right| + 1$$

Of course

$$f(x) = \left| \mathbb{P} \cap \lbrace 3, \ldots, x \rbrace \right|$$

where $\mathbb{P}$ denotes the set of prime numbers or simply *let $f$ be the prime counting function* is even simpler.